# Can install be used to stage symlinks?

Tags: command-line, symlink, coreutils

Can `install` be used to install symlinks without dereferencing and installing the target file - it seems like such an unusual omission?

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 greg greg 4096 Aug 20 10:46 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 greg greg 4096 Aug 20 10:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 greg greg    4 Aug 20 10:46 stest -> test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg greg    0 Aug 20 10:40 test
$ mkdir target
$ install test  target/test
$ install stest  target/stest
$ ls -la target/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 greg greg 4096 Aug 20 10:46 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 greg greg 4096 Aug 20 10:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 greg greg    0 Aug 20 10:46 stest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 greg greg    0 Aug 20 10:46 test
```

Is there an alternative tool that more provides the base `install` functionality as well as safe staging of symlinks?

Comment: PS - the obvious tag `install` for this question is deprecated as it has been used incorrectly for installation - perhaps it could be clarified to refer specifically to this 'standard' command-line tool.

Comment: Why not simply use `ln`?

Comment: `install` allows custom setting of uid/gid and access mode, creation of directories in the path, safe handling of existing files, along with binary stripping - for my application all of these features were critical - it just chokes on symlinks.  `ln` does none of those things.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I have is something along the lines of:

```
# mess around extracting src/dest from install's $@ params
#  ...
if [ -h $src ]; then
    rm -f $dest
    [ -d $(dirname $dest) ] || install -d $(dirname $dest) ...install args... $(dirname $src)
    cp -d $src $dest
else
    install $@
fi
```

The mess around extracting args bit is a pain in the...

Comment: `$dest` isn't always the last argument of `install` with `-t` or `-d`. I'm unsure of interactions with `-T`and symlinks.  Do you have argument parsing code to share as well?